# Looking for ways to implement the migrateBU gist given by salesforce for MobilePushSDK

Tags: mobilepush, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush-android, app-development

> Questions I have about implementation
>
> 1. When I import this method 'context' is not found and Im not sure I am setting it up properly.
> 2. Will I be able to switch BU and register a contact for 2 BUs without having to restart the application
>
> Use Case: app starts contact registers to BU #1 while app is running this function triggers and registers same contact for BU #2

```
private fun migrateBU() {
  MarketingCloudSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->

// Gather the data from the existing BU that you want to migrate
var attributes: Map<String, String>
var tags: Set<String>
var contactKey: String?

with(sdk.registrationManager) {
  attributes = this.attributes
  tags = this.tags
  contactKey = this.contactKey
}

    // Register a registration listener which will be called upon a successful registration
    sdk.registrationManager.registerForRegistrationEvents {

      // Re-initialize the SDK with new BU credentials
      MarketingCloudSdk.init(context, MarketingCloudConfig.builder().apply {
        setApplicationId("{new BU application id}")
        setAccessToken("{new BU access token}")
        setMarketingCloudServerUrl("{new BU Marketing Cloud server URL}")
        // Other configuration values as required -- nothing will be carried over from previous configurations
      }.build(context)) {
        when (it.status) {
          InitializationStatus.Status.SUCCESS -> {
            setDataInNewBU(attributes, tags, contactKey)
          }
          else -> {
            // Handle Failure
          }
        }
      }
    }
    // Disable Push which will trigger a Registration
    sdk.pushMessageManager.disablePush()
  }
}

private fun setDataInNewBU(attributes: Map<String, String>, tags: Set<String>, contactKey: String?) {
  MarketingCloudSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
    sdk.registrationManager.edit().apply {
      attributes.forEach {
        setAttribute(it.key, it.value)
      }
      addTags(tags)
      contactKey?.let {
        setContactKey(it)
      }
      commit()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Registering a customer in 2 separate BUs and expecting both registrations to remain active is not a supported use case as of 20210311.

Comment: Do not do this. It will fail. You will be unhappy with the result. I don't know how to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your use-case is not supported.  The gist is intended to migrate customers between BUs but it is not supported to have a single customer registered in 2 different BUs at the same time.  This might seem to work, but it will encounter synchronization issues, etc.  `Do Not` do this.

Change `private fun migrateBU() {` to `private fun migrateBU(context: Context) {` and pass context into the function.

Comment: Hey thanks very much for your response.
I understand you think this would be a poor way to handle this.

is there any documentation on how to handle registering a contact for 2 BU's without having to restart the application?

Comment: No.  There is no documentation for this as it is an unsupported use-case.  Do not do this.  It will fail.  You will be unhappy with the result.  I don't know how to be more clear.